# MongoDB Compass has encountered an unexpected error SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I want to use `mongodb compass` but not installing and getting this error. Earlier it was working fine, but now its not responding to the installer and after installation getting this error

```
MongoDB Compass has encountered an unexpected error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What is the folder where you like to install the tool?

Comment: ProgramFiles in c drive